# ListView.Builder in Riverpod not updating properly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, riverpod, flutter-listview

I'am developing an app with flutter and **flutter_riverpod**. I want to use listview.Builder with riverpod. But I got some problems it just doesn't update the list when i add a nother user to the liste. I am pretty new so any tips would help a lot
**Providers Page:**

```
final users_liste_pro = StateProvider((ref) {
  return liste;
});
final events_liste_pro = StateProvider((ref) {
  return events_liste;
});
final txt = StateProvider((ref) {
  return 0;
});
```

**liste:**

```
var liste=[
  User(0,"adam","0000000","zone2","0000000","0000000000",null,false),
User(1,"adam","0000000000","zone4","0000000","0000000000",null,false),

];
```

**ConsumerWidget:**

```
class event_page extends ConsumerWidget {
  Event event ;
  event_page(this.event);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context,WidgetRef ref) {

    final users = ref.watch(users_liste_pro);

    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Event"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: size.width,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 5,),
            Center(child: Text(event.name,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),)),
            Text("  Payed List :"),
            **//only way i could solve it is by addig this variable DOWN BELOW IS FULL COMMENT**
            *Text(ref.watch(txt).toString()),*
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: users.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return eventpage_card(users[index],index);
                  }
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){
        ref.read(users_liste_pro.notifier).state.add(User(400, "name", 'tele', "zone", "ville",           "quartier",null, true));
        **//only way I could solve it is by adding this variable that i shown in a simple text in    the page if i dont add it the other ref.watch for the list doesnt work**
        *ref.read(txt.notifier).state++;*
      },),
    );
  }
}
```

weird but working solution is I added another StateProvider that only returns an int and each time I want to add a user I increment the number but I know that I must be doing something wrong

```
ref.read(users_liste_pro.notifier).state.add(User(400, "name", 'tele', "zone", "ville",
"quartier",null, true));
//only way i could solve it is by adding this variable that i shown in a simple text in the page if i dont add it the other ref.watch for the list doesnt work
ref.read(txt.notifier).state++;
```

**after i added StateNotifierProvider the first error was fixed but now the lists index doesnt update for some reason:**

```
class Userlistnotifier extends StateNotifier<List<User>>{   Userlistnotifier(): super([...liste]);

  void add(){
    state=[...state,User(400, "name", 'tele', "zone", "ville", "quartier",null, true)];
  }
}
final Userlist_provider=StateNotifierProvider<Userlistnotifier,List<User> >((ref) => Userlistnotifier());

final users2 = ref.watch(Userlist_provider);

ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: users2.length,//this lenght does not update
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return eventpage_card(users2[index],index);
                  }
              ),
```

Comment: The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state updates only when new values is assigned to the state. So use the following code:

```dart
final newUser = User(400, "name", 'tele', "zone", "ville", "quartier", null, true);
ref.read(users_liste_pro.notifier).update((value) => [...value, newUser]);
```

Also, it is not recommended to use `StateProvider` for compex objects.

> For more advanced cases, consider using StateNotifierProvider instead
> and create a StateNotifier class. While the initial boilerplate will
> be a bit larger, having a custom StateNotifier class is critical for
> the long-term maintainability of your project – as it centralizes the
> business logic of your state in a single place.

Comment: thank you very much, just one more error if you couuld help.